# @Viewchild is not working inside Directive, but working in Component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am just playing around with @ViewChild/@ContentChild, and I was surprised to see that the @ViewChild is not working inside directive and is working fine for component.But in Directive its not working. I tried with AfterViewInit hook, so life cycle hook is not the reason. Something else is the issue here,Please find the code below.

**app.component.html**

```
<div appMain >
  <div #testContentDiv style="background-color: grey">
    <p>This is the first p tag</p>
    <p>This is the second p tag</p> 
  </div>
  <div #testViewDiv style="background-color: yellow">
    <p>This is the first p tag</p>
    <p>This is the second p tag</p>
  </div>
  <app-test-child></app-test-child>
</div>
```

**test-dir.ts** --**Directive**

```
import { Directive, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMain]'
})
export class MainDirective implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }
  // tslint:disable-next-line:member-ordering
  @ContentChild('testContentDiv') testContent: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('testViewDiv') testView: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit() {
    //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
    //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.
    // console.log(this.test.nativeElement);

  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    //Called after ngOnInit when the component's or directive's content has been initialized.
    //Add 'implements AfterContentInit' to the class.
    console.log('Content Div: ngAfterContentInit:  ' + this.testContent.nativeElement);
    // console.log('View Div: ngAfterContentInit: ' + this.testView.nativeElement);


  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //Called after ngAfterContentInit when the component's view has been initialized. Applies to components only.
    //Add 'implements AfterViewInit' to the class.
    console.log('Content Div:ngAfterViewInit: ' + this.testContent.nativeElement);
    console.log('View Div: ngAfterViewInit: ' + this.testView.nativeElement);

  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "App works";

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using Angular v4.1.3 with Cli

Comment: _I was surprised to see that the @ViewChild is not working inside directiv_ - directives don't have views/templates, what were you expecting to find? `@ContentChild` should work

Comment: ContentChild does work. But why not ViewChild? I am not trying to view any template, instead I am trying it reference the element using ViewChild which is already initialised for the component

Comment: Think directive are mare metadata/tags... to identify/ help other stuff ...just to avoid confusion..

Answer (score 10):

At least as of Angular v6.x:

Accoring to the [Angular source code for directives](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.7/packages/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L200), it is indeed possible to select children. However, the standard way of just using the `@ViewChildren` or `@ContentChildren` decorators does not appear to work for me. Also, I am unable to get `@ViewChildren` to work despite the docs.

`@ContentChildren`, however, *does* work for me. You need to decorate the Directive itself with the queries property as such (this directive is dumbed down for clarity, you'll still need a selector and other stuff to make it work):

```
@Directive({
  queries: {
    // Give this the same name as your local class property on the directive. "myChildren" in this case
    myChildren: new ContentChildren(YourChild),
  },
})
export class MyDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  // Define the query list as a property here, uninitialized.
  private myChildren: QueryList<YourChild>;

  /**
   * ngAfterContentInit Interface Method
   */
  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    // myChildren is now initialized and ready for use.
  }
}
```

This suffices for me so I'm not going to waste more time figuring out why `ViewChildren` doesn't work. My understanding of the difference between `ViewChildren` and `ContentChildren`is that `ContentChildren` selects from `<ng-content>` tags, where `ViewChildren` selects straight from the view itself. So, the behavior *seems* backwards to me, but there is probably a justification for it.

As expected, `ContentChildren` are not available until the `ngAfterContentInit` hook, so don't let that one bite you.

Comment: I was able to get ViewChild with this method as well. Thanks.

Comment: Correction: You were able to get _ContentChildren_ with this method. They are different.

Comment: Sometimes you need to stop the command `ng serve` and do it again. I suppose it not always reload correctly. This cost me more than 1h

Answer (score 3):

> There are three kinds of directives in Angular:
>
> Components — directives with a template.
>
> Structural directives — change the DOM layout by adding and removing DOM elements.
>
> Attribute directives — change the appearance or behavior of an element, component, or another directive.

So by definition Components are the only directive with a `template` so you can find `@ViewChild` only for components.

Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#directive-overview).

Hope this helps!!

Comment: If it cannot be used in directive, then why does it compile?? And also ViewChild documentation doesn't say that it cannot be used, there is something else that I am missing here

Comment: I am not trying view the template, but instead I am trying to get reference to the initialised template through ViewChild, shouldn't that be possible??

Comment: `ViewChild` are the HTML elements withing the template of component, and  `ContentChild` are the HTML elements within the directives tags (for e.g. `<my-dir> <div>hello i am content </div> </my-dir>` ), hence you can find content child for all directives but ViewChild only for components as they have templates.

Comment: Except if you read the source code for directives: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6.1.7/packages/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L200
It clearly states that you can have view and content child queries. So, no, you're wrong - there is a way to do this. I cannot get it to work yet but will post an answer when I figure it out.

Comment: Curious - has anyone figured this out yet?

Comment: Untrue, also attribute directives can be found with `@ViewChild` (have been working with this for years already). Only for `@ViewChildren` it is different 